# Remove strings from a string in android

Tags: android, string

I am getting a string from json

*`"author":"ricobeemer<\/span>"`* .

And when i am  retrieving the string

`String author = c.getString("author");`

"author" string show me
`<span class="reviewer"itmprop="name">ricobeemer</span>`

where as i just want to store "ricobeemer" in author string.
Can anyone help me how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick question : why is there html in your json ? it would seem you are mixing data and presentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and best

```
Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
Html.fromHtml(author).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day. That is what i actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way to get it done:

```
String author = c.getString("author")
    .substring(c.getString("author")
    .lastIndexOf("\">"), c.getString("author").lastIndexOf("</"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a bit of regex matching to extract from between the `>` and `<` like so:

```
String author = c.getString("author");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(author);
if (m.find()) {
    author = m.group();
}
```